# Change profile picture in YouTube

Tags: youtube, profile-picture

How do I change my profile picture on YouTube?

I never set it up and it seems to be a thumbnail of one of the videos I uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change this via the **Account** setting page.
Click on your username to open the drop-down list, on which you can see the 'Account' option
Then click on the '**change**' hyper link beneath the **profile picture** box.
Browse and select a new profile picture.
Done

Answer (score 3):

1. Sign into your YouTube account and
   click the 'Account' link at the top
   right hand corner of the page
2. Click the large blue 'My Account'
   link in the top left hand corner of
   the screen.
3. In the left hand navigation column,
   click Profile Setup.
4. Click the '**Change Picture**' button and
   select the file that you'd like to
   display as your thumbnail profile
   icon on your channel (you can either
   select an image or a still frame from
   one of your videos).
5. Don't forget to click the 'Save Changes' button to save the update
   you just made to your channel.

From here: http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=83336